# Show alert when screenshot is taken and require text input

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

Wanted to see if there was a way to display an alert view after screenshot is taken, and then require text input that matches a specific string. If the user doesn't input the right text, then the alert view doesn't dismiss and the user is prompted to retry. If the user inputs the correct text, the alert view is dismissed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this

```
let requireTextInput = "require text input"
// add observer for screen shot    
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main, using:
        { notification in

            var inputTextField = UITextField()

            let textPrompt = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "require text input", preferredStyle: .alert)

            textPrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))

            textPrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {
                (action) -> Void in
            // if the input match the required text

                let str = inputTextField.text
                if str == requireTextInput {
                    print("right")
                } else {
                    print("wrong")
                }

            }))

            textPrompt.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(textField: UITextField!) in
                textField.placeholder = "place Holder"
                inputTextField = textField

            })

            self.present(textPrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)

    })
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks. For some reason, the navigation bar slides out of the view. Any way to make it no slide away?

Comment: if you would like to keep navigation bar. you could change the last line to "navigationController?.pushViewController"

Comment: Doesn't seem to work as the entire view gets pushed to a new view controller with a blank screen and a keyboard. This is with: "                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(textPrompt, animated: false)"

Comment: I had tested on my Xcode. Use normal navigation controller, and "self.present". The navigation bar did not slide out of the screen. Maybe you set hide navigation bar in other part of your code.

Comment: What should the code be for it? "self.navigationController?.pushViewController(textPrompt, animated: false) navigationController?.pushViewController"? Sorry, new to Swift. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think "self.present" is better. "navigationController?.pushViewController" preform a segue, and add a child view controller. Alert view is just a pop over view. I use "self.present" on my test project, the navigation bar did not slide out of the screen.

Comment: Trying: "                self.present.navigationController?.pushViewController(textPrompt, animated: false, completion: nil)" but getting an error: Value of type (UIViewController, Bool, (() -> Void)?) -> Void has no member 'navigationController".

Comment: Just "self.present(textPrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131458/discussion-between-miles-and-t-w).